# Load serialized data in to an array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a jquery plugin used to re-order lists, the data that gets provided is serialized.

For example:

```
[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18}]}]
```

My plan is to submit the data in to a php script, load it in to an array, and then save different parts of the given data in different rows in the database.

I'm having an issue loading this data in to an array though, my code is as follows:

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data . "<br /><br />";

$arr = unserialize($data);

echo var_dump($arr);

?>
```

However, when attempting to run the script with the sample of data above, I get the following error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 144 bytes in D:..... on line 5

Comment: Looks like JSON, not a serialized array.

Comment: this could explain where im going wrong... ill try JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, it is `json` and PHP got it's own functions for that:

```
$arr = json_decode($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Serialize functions typically do not work on JSON. Use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) instead:

```
$data = '[{"id":13},{"id":14},{"id":15,"children":[{"id":16},{"id":17},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18},{"id":18}]}]';
$json = json_decode($data, true); // true flag makes it an array instead of an object
print_r($json);
```

This will return the following:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 13 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 14 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 15 [children] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 16 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 17 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) [9] => Array ( [id] => 18 ) ) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function.

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
echo $data . "<br /><br />";

$arr = json_decode($data, true);

echo var_dump($arr);

?>
```

This should work for you.